# Como sacar si una variable existe?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo el siguiente script de consulta en una base de datos quien me ayude lo agradezco estoy intentando saber si la variable @ esta en el rango de numeros 1 al 100 alguien me saca esta duda?

```
DECLARE 
@X varchar (6) = 1001

 if (SELECT @X = BETWEEN 1 and 100 )
print 'Esta dentro del indice' 
ELSE
print 'Esta Fuera'
```

Eso fue lo que se me ocurrio y no me resulto. Agradecido de ante mano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las asignaciones a variables varchar, se deben de realizar con los valores entre apóstrofes. Aunque realmente es funcional realizarlo directamente como has hecho, no es lo más correcto.

```
DECLARE 
@X varchar (6) = 99;

if (@X >= 1 and @x <= 100)
    print 'Esta dentro del índice' 
ELSE
    print 'Esta Fuera';
```

Esta puede ser una solución, evaluando el valor de la variable "sin Select".

Esta puede ser la más "ortodoxa". Asignas el valor entre apóstrofes y luego en la evaluación, casteas el mismo a int.

```
DECLARE @X varchar(6) = '99';

if (cast(@X as int) >= 1 and cast(@x as int) <= 100)
    print 'Esta dentro del índice' 
ELSE
    print 'Esta Fuera';
```

Si el varchar puede contener otros caracteres no numéricos, entonces puedes utilizar try_cast

```
DECLARE @X varchar(6) = 'a';

if (try_cast(@X as int) >= 1 and try_cast(@x as int) <= 100)
    print 'Esta dentro del índice' 
ELSE
    print 'Esta Fuera';
```